# Is there a way to automate user interaction with an android app?

Tags: android, automation, user-interaction

I want to develop an app which can simulate user interaction on a web site. For example the user types in a username and a password and a text. The app automatically goes on facebook, logs in with the given username and password and then makes a post with the text.

I already tried using Espresso and UIAutomator but these tools are only for testing.

Answer (score 0):

UIAutomator is tool used for mobile automation. Use selenium to create script for automating above task on web.

Comment: No, UIAutomator and selenium are tools for TESTautomation, i don't want to test i want to simulate user interactions like said before.